# non-linear equation using for loop and fsolve

Tags: matlab

I am currently working on a project which requires me to solve a function where the constant changes between set limits and then plot the function.

I've run this code but this error pops up: "Undefined function or variable 'x'.

> Error in basicfun (line 4) 
>      p(i)=x.^3-27.*a "

```
a=0:0.1:1;
for i=1:length(a)

   p(i)=x.^3-27.*a
end
x0=1;
[x,fval]=fsolve(prob,x0);
disp(p)
plot(p)
```

What is expected to happen is that "a" starts at 0, and gives a solution for x at p(0) to p(11) to a=1 at which point x=3.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to find the solution of the equation when I vary the value of "a".

Comment: And is $x_0 $ always the same for any value of $a$?

Comment: is it supposed to change?, I thought `x0` was just a guess value, which is why I assigned it to 1.

Answer (score 0):

From what I saw, it's because the directives' position:

```
x0=1;
[x,fval]=fsolve(prob,x0);
a=0:0.1:1;
for i=1:length(a)
   p(i)=x.^3-27.*a
end
disp(p)
plot(p)
```

You used `x` before it is given a value.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I understood how to use fsolve properly. There is something wrong with the loop which I have to figure out.